# Integrate $\int^\frac{T}{2}_0\frac{dt}{\pi ^2 t^2 (\csc^2 \frac{\pi t}{T}) -T^2}$.

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int^\frac{T}{2}_0 \frac{dt}{\pi ^2 t^2 (\csc^2 \frac{\pi t}{T})-T^2}.$$

**My work**. Let $u=\frac{\pi t}{T}$, then $du=\frac{\pi}{T}dt$ and
$$\frac{T}{\pi} \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{du}{u^2 T^2 (\csc^2 u)-T^2}=\frac{1}{\pi T} \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{du}{u^2 (\csc^2 u) -1}.$$

Please help! I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Have you also the llmits of integration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. For $T>0$,
$$\int^\frac{T}{2}_0 \frac{dt}{\pi ^2 t^2 (\csc^2 \frac{\pi t}{T})-T^2}=\frac{1}{\pi T} \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{du}{u^2 \csc^2 u -1}.$$
Now, note that in a right neighbourhood of $0$:
$$0<\frac{1}{u^2 (\csc^2 u) -1}=\frac{\sin^2 u}{u^2-\sin^2 u}=\frac{u^2+o(u^2)}{u^2-(u^2-2\frac{u\cdot u^3}{3!}+o(u^4))}=\frac{u^2+o(u^2)}{\frac{u^4}{3}+o(u^4)}\sim \frac{3}{u^2}$$
so the integral diverges to $+\infty$.